# Form of Russian adverbs

Tags: наречия

Does the short neuter form of adjectives always automatically constitute the corresponding adverb, or are there cases of the short neuter form and the adverb having different forms/stress patterns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Равный** yields the short neuter **равнó** but the adverb is **рáвно**. I think there are other adverbs that don't follow suit when the corresponding short adjective shifts stress to the last syllable.

Then, most passive participles with the suffix  `-нн-` lose the second `н` in the short form, while the adverb keeps it geminated: **растерянный** — **общество растеряно**, but **растерянно улыбнуться**. That can also be accompanied by a non-matching stress shift: **определенó** (adj.) vs. **определённо** (adv.)

Comment: бОльно vs. больнО.

Comment: There is no such form больнО. You probably meant вольнО: "вольнО ж без работы гулять"

Comment: @ddbug: *больно надо* vs. *животное больно*.